# Finding a substring within a PHP array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a PHP script that loops through each row of a CSV file and organizes each line into an array:

```
$counter = 0;
    $file = file($ReturnFile);
    foreach($file as $k){
        if(preg_match('/"/', $k)==1){
            $csv[] = explode(',', $k);
            $counter++;
         }
     }

    ...

    while($x<$counter){
        $line=$csv[$x];
```

This works; my question is about how to find a substring within each line. This:

```
    foreach($line as $value){
        if($value==$name_search){
            // action
```

works if the value of `$line` is exactly equal to the value of `$name_search` (`$name_search` is a person's last name). However, this doesn't work if there is a space or additional characters in the value of `$line` (for example: `$line` equal to "Wilson (ID: 345)" or "Wilson " won't match a `$name_search` value of "Wilson".

So far I've tried:

```
if(strpos($value, $res_name_search) !== false){

if(substr($value, 0, strrpos($value, ' '))==$res_name_search){

if(substr(strval($value), 0, strrpos(strval($value), ' '))==$res_name_search){
```

without success ... Do I have a syntax error and/or is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: I think the issue should be related to the Upper Case or Lower Case. Try lower case both strings. strpos() could work.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have inverted the parameters. The following should work:

```
if (strpos($res_name_search, $value) !== false)
```

A minor note: use `stripos` for case-insensitive search.

Comment: No, the first parameter is the haystack (`$line`) and the second is the needle (`$name_search`), so @faalbane's order of the function arguments is correct

Comment: tested; same issue

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) like this: `if (strpos($res_name_search, $value))`

Comment: tested; same issue

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

```
if (preg_match('/'.strtolower($res_name_search).'/', strtolower($value)))
```

Comment: tested; same issue

Answer (score 0):

1. use php TRIM function
2. Convert to either of the lowercase or uppercase before compairing
3. use var_dump to check the data type
4. instead of using var_dump type cast $value and $name_search to STRING
5. also check ===
6. Remove spaces (if required)
7. Use regular expression to remove (, ), :, -, ; etc...
8. and of course apply function strpos

You can apply above mentioned points in your logic (Order of points may be different)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$str = 'This is my test: wilson ';
$search = "wilson";

if(strpos(strtolower($str), strtolower($search)) !== false){
    echo 'found it';
}
```

Comment: tested; same issue

Comment: then should be something else in your code. If you test this code here. http://phptester.net/ will work. Try it!

Answer (score 0):

This is the sort of situations for which the built-in PHP function `stristr` exists. This function is the case-insensitive equivalent of the `strstr` function which, according to the docs:

> Returns part of haystack string starting from and including the first occurrence of needle to the end of haystack.

Using this function, achieving such a task becomes as easy as:

```
foreach($line as $value){
    if( stristr($value, $name_search) !== FALSE){
        // substring was found in search string, perform your action
```

You can read more about it in the [official documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php)

I hope this helps.

Comment: tested; same issue

Comment: Ok, the confusion was coming from the way you used `$value` and `$name_search`. I've inverted the order of the two  variables in my answer. That should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I advice you to use [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) function, this will return you an array of your columns for each iteration as follow :

```
 while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
 // ...
 }
```

If in your CSV file, the column **NAME** is in position 2 for example and you want to know if token exist, just use

```
if (strpos('Wilson', $data[2] !== FALSE) {
    // do your job
}
```

if you want to deal with case-insentivie, use [stripos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php) function